# GCM Error MismatchSenderId with Updated project number

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an android test project which uses GCM and it was working last week. A few days ago I've started to receive the "MismatchSenderId" out of nowhere when I try to send a message from the server to my clients (I've tried 3 different clients I have). I didn't even logged into the google developer console.

I've tried deleting the credential from the google console and creating a new one, and unregister and re-register the client devices, with no results.

I've googled, but I mostly found issues related to project numbers changed a long ago (issue I had and corrected) and suggestions about creating a new project at the google console.

I won't create a new project without knownig what happened here. I can't afford this once I have the app developed; I'd rather create my own message system.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you start getting these errors after changing the project number? Did you change the sender ID used to register your app to GCM?

Comment: Hi Eran, thanks for your answer. Doing screen caps I've noticed that the project number at the google console and the project number declared on the android project (hardcoded into a class) didn't match! Since the project was working last week, I'm the only who has access to the source code and google console, and I don't sleepcode... could the project number be changed by google this week? I didn't even  changed code on the push class this month... I don't know; I've changed the sender id for the "new" one and it's working now. Thank you very much!

Comment: You should note that if you have old registration IDs in your DB (that were generated for the old project number), using them would still give you the mismatch sender id error.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, Eran. I have 3 users on my DB (it's still a test project), I've deleted an re-created database, table and records several times since I updated the project number a few months ago and, also, I was using the same users as the last week.

Answer (score 0):

Google project number was different from the one declared in my android project. I don't know what happened. Does google periodically change project numbers? I've faced this months ago and I've found project number was changed by google a long time ago... could it happened again?

Thank you very much!